# is there a way to get the result of web3's encodeFunctionCall with ethers?

Tags: ethers.js

I'm using web3 to get the RLP encoded data for a function call like so

```
const safeTransferFrom: any = tokenERC1155Abi.find((f) => f.name === 'safeTransferFrom');
const params: Array<any> = [identity, minterAddr, 1, amount, '0x0'];
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(safeTransferFrom, params);
```

is there a way to achieve the same result with the `ethers.js` library?

Comment: Nice i was looking for this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The equivalent in ethers.js involves first creating an "interface" object and calling a method on that:

```
> let ABI = [ "function transfer(address to, uint amount)" ];
> let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI);
> iface.encodeFunctionData("transfer", [ <function_params> ])
```

[Taken from here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/478)

Comment: sucks tbh, why not straightforward like truffles?

Answer (score 2):

Get first the fragment of abi function

```
const fragment = contract.interface.getFunction(method)
```

Then, get bytes4 signature of function

```
const selectorHash = contract.interface.getSighash(fragment)
```